# Eagerloading Matrix fields resulting in empty array

Tags: matrix, globals, eager-loading

I'm trying to eager-load a Matrix field with it's blocktype and related field types. For some reason the _eagerLoadedBlockTypeElements are empty arrays.

If I get rid of the `with` clause on ElementCriteria and iterate through the items it does work, which is not surprising.

The code I have right now (including dumping the results) are below.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::GlobalSet, [
        'handle' => 'footer',
        'with'   => ['column1Items.item:itemSection', 'column1Items.item:itemTitle']
    ]);

$found = $criteria->first();
dump($found->getEagerLoadedElements('column1Items'));
exit();
```

I'm fairly new to Craft and working with Yii hopefully someone can help me out with this one!

Thanks!

P.S. I can dump the query logs if necessary, just shoot!

Comment: I've just run in to this same issue, no luck in my troubleshooting so far.